# CSS Linking to HTML

Tags: html, css

I have linked a CSS file to different HTML files around my site. The CSS file is stored in the root of my site. The file only works with the homepage, in the root folder (cPanelX file manager). The other pages will not display the main CSS. My HTML linking code follows. It is from the sub-pages, not in the site's root folder (even though  the code is the same on the homepage HTML file). How do I get the sub-pages to display the main CSS?

```
<link href="homepagecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I am really new to this, and any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Sounds like a path issue. Try putting a `/` in front of your css file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `/`

```
<link href="/homepagecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Not a problem. Don't forget to click the tick for an accepted answer :).